# Is it necessary to use pickit for pic MCU?

Tags: pic, pickit

Recently I bought PIC18f4550 dvelopment board by OUMEX. I started go through online tutorials and mess around MPLAB IDE to use it. While setting up a new project, I was asked to select a tool as shown in the picture below. I was not aware about these tools. I looked up online and its costs $70 plus (WOW) and takes about 5 days to deliver (In meanwhile I wouldn't have much to do).

Back to my question is it necessary for me to use these tools to program my MCU? How does it benefits or affects my coding overall

Thanks in advance!  [image: new project screenshot]

EDIT:
Thank you everyone for you explanation. I think my research wasn't proper enough that I didn't even know that a I needed a PIC Programmer. Till now I worked on the development boards like arduino uno, Silicon labs 8051, etc which had it inside them so it didn't strike me that the development board I bought didn't have it. I just assumed that it would be embedded inside.
Now I kinda regret not asking for suggestions on which kind of MCU I should have chosen. Since PIC18F4550 has been in the market for a good time, so troubleshooting it wouldn't take up so much time. Anyways lets hope for the best! Again thank you so much. Your insight has helped me.

Comment: $70 for which tool? The Pickit3 sells for much less than that.

Comment: http://sg.element14.com/microchip/pg164130/debugger-pickit-3-usb-programmer/dp/1771323

Comment: Just to make sure, you realize that's in Singapore dollars, right? That's equal to $50 USD.

Comment: Yes. I am from Singapore.

Comment: You NEED a programmer to program PIC. Original PicKIT or clone or any other flavor of programmer.

Comment: @Chupacabras _technically_ speaking, I suppose one could manually clock in the program, assuming the PICs don't have timing requirements on the programming protocol.  ARM cores don't like to be programed at less than about 100khz, but the CC2541 will happily accept slow clock speeds.  However, I doubt anyone wants to spend hours flipping switching just to save a few bucks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what board you bought?

Comment: @PeterGreen Link: https://www.olimex.com/Products/PIC/Proto/PIC-USB-4550/resources/PIC-USB-4550.pdf

Comment: Now I am having another issue which I believe should have its own topic. the link to it is: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/289165/issues-with-olimex-pic18f4550

Answer (score 2):

Almost all micro controllers need a dedicated tool to write the firmware in to the chip. Atmel, ST, Microchip all have there own tool. You can buy micro controllers with a boot loader that will enable you to write the firmware with a UART. (example: Picaxe and Arduino)

There are 3th party clones available. A quick search on Ebay for pickit 3: They sell for $11 to $20.

DM164140 - MPLABXpress Evaluation Board is a nice alternative. It has a programmer build in. It's easy to get started.

Comment: Currently I have is this one: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/338177.pdf?_ga=1.268190221.2065275697.1484290306

Comment: I really can't directly upload the code and use it with the one I have?

Comment: Username, no. That is not programmer, that is just development board. That is just board you can plug your programmed PIC to and run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using another PIC microcontroller then you can get the Microchip Curiosity board which comes with a PIC16f1619 and a programmer built in for about $30. If you specifically want to use that chip then you can get cheap Chinese knock offs of the pickit 3 for less than $20 in some cases. I have one and I can't tell the difference between the fake one and the real one that I use at work.

Answer (score 0):

> Back to my question is it necessary for me to use these tools to program my MCU?

To be sure, a pic can be programmed without thee use off any of those tools.

> How does it benefits or affects my coding overall

They make programming easier, and. They make coding more efficient, as you rarely need to wonder if your programmer is part of thee problem.

If you are making a living out of this, get  the best tool you can afford and skim on anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need *something* that gets the bits into the target PIC.  This has to be able to communicate with a PC on one side, and wiggle the programming lines of the PIC appropriately on the other side.  Such things are usually called *PIC programmers*.

As far as I'm aware, my [LProg](http://www.microchipdirect.com/ProductSearch.aspx?Keywords=TEMLP001) PIC programmer is the lowest cost of all the ones out that *that actually follow the rules* for both the host and PIC interfaces.  However, one reason it can be made so cheaply is because it only supports those PICs that can be programmed with everything at 3.3 V and don't need a high voltage to enter programming mode.  This is true of pretty much all newer PICs, but not the old 18F4550 you are using.  Most of the old parts have newer replacements that are largely compatible, such as the 18F45J50, that do work with the LProg.

However, as much as I'd like to sell you a LProg, you're better off with one of the PicKits from Microchip.  This is because these also function as low end debuggers.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that there is no low voltage only pic programmers out there - this so the first time I heard of lprog. I have toyed around with building a lv-only pickit2 - use thee same PCB , casing and software but limited to lvp only. One of those days, ...

Answer (score 0):

> @PeterGreen Link: olimex.com/Products/PIC/Proto/PIC-USB-4550/resources/… – EEE 6 mins ago

Afaict (the documenation is not especially clear) your specific board has what is known as a "bootloader" on it. This allows you to reprogram most of the PICs program memory without needing an external programmer.

The downside of bootloaders are you lose a small ammount of program memory, you need to use special linker scripts that take account of the bootloader and you often have to use tools specific too the bootloader to do the actual programming.

They say the board comes with the "microchip USB bootloader". I am not 100% sure what they mean by this, but I expect they mean the same bootloader that shipped on microchip's official "PICdem FS USB". If so then you should be able to use the tools intended for that board to program it.

You can find the documentation/software related to the microchip "PICdem FS USB" at http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM163025 I belive you want the "USB Framework" download.

Unfortunately said tools are getting a bit long in the tooth now, so you may well have to find a 32-bit windows system to use them.