# Issues with OLIMEX PIC18F4550

Tags: pic, microchip, pickit

I am having issue with my OLIMEX PIC18F4550
([link](https://www.olimex.com/Products/PIC/Proto/PIC-USB-4550/resources/PIC-USB-4550.pdf)).

I am not able to view any tools in my IPE.

[image: IPE]

I am using PICkit 3 from Microchip. I think the issue might be that OLIMEX isn't powering up. I have connected it to my PC via USB. But I don't understand why its not powering up. I have attached the connection of PICkit 3 and OLIMEX.

[image: PICkit 3]

Kindly tell me what is it what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you not seeing your PICkit 3 from your computer or is your PICkit 3 not seeing the OLIMEX board? These are two separate things here which will help to track where's the problem.

Comment: The 'Tool' you should be seeing is the PICkit, not your dev board. Plug the PICkit in by itself, check your Device Mangler (or Manager if you prefer), re-install drivers, etc.

Comment: @brhans I have tried another PICkit and still the same thing. I think I will try reinstalling IDE and IPE and see if the issue still persists

Comment: Have you tried with PICkit by itself? Make sure the PICkit3 firmware is current, and let us know if you see any LED activity on the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wanting to power the OLIMEX board from USB. Make sure you select USB as the power supply with the **PWR Select** connector (USB/EXT). You can see the connection from the schematic in the PDF you linked, page 4.

Comment: I connected the power jack with OLIMEX board and tried again (with and without USB connection with my PC) however I still couldn't see any option under Tools.